# How can I store and retrieve user selections from a JFileChooser from a seperate class?

Tags: java, jfilechooser

I'm writing some code to allow the selection of either one of multiple file directories which I will work with from there. I want to call a function from a separate class to find the user selection(s). I have a global ArrayList that is added to based on whether one or multiple directories is chosen. The issue I'm having is that when I try to call a function to return that ArrayList, that code is always run before the user input is finished so it just returns a blank ArrayList because nothing has been input.

This is the code for the file chooser:

```
package application;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.*;

public class FileExplorer extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    //Intiate Buttons and File Chooser
    JButton openButton = new JButton("Choose a File Directory...);
    JButton openMultipleButton = new JButton("Choose Multiple File Directories...");

    JFileChooser chooser;
    ArrayList<File> filesChosen = new ArrayList<File>();
    String choosertitle = "Show Picker";

    public FileExplorer() {

        //Add buttons and listeners
        add(openButton);
        openButton.addActionListener(this);

        add (openMultipleButton);
        openMultipleButton.addActionListener(this);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        //set chooser parameters
        chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.setDialogTitle(choosertitle);
        chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);

        if (e.getActionCommand().matches("Choose Multiple File Directories...")){

            //Set selection to allow multiple choices
            chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);

            if (chooser.showOpenDialog(this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File[] numFiles = chooser.getSelectedFiles();
                for (int i = 0; i < numFiles.length; i++) {
                    filesChosen.add(numFiles[i]);
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("No Selection ");
            }
        } else {

            //Don't allow multiple choices
            chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(false);

            //return shows
            if (chooser.showOpenDialog(this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                filesChosen.add(chooser.getSelectedFile());
            } else {
                System.out.println("No Selection ");
            }
        }

        //
        //


    }

    public ArrayList<File> getFiles() {
        return filesChosen;
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 200);
    }

    public void launch() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("");
        FileExplorer panel = new FileExplorer();
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel, "Center");
        frame.setSize(panel.getPreferredSize());
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
```

This is the call I'm using in the other class just to test if it's working:

```
FileExplorer fe = new FileExplorer();
fe.launch();
System.out.println(fe.getFiles());
```

I've also attempted editing the function in question to re-check the ArrayList like so:

```
public ArrayList<File> getFiles() {
        if (filesChosen.isEmpty() ==false) {
            return filesChosen;
        } else {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                getFiles();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }    
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

but the variable never updated. Even after user input. I'm at a loss and I'd appreciate any help with this issue.